# How do you pass a require('') object into the scope of the bind object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the javascript bind function to pass a file that I've required into the scope, and have it use that object's functionality to execute some code.

It's a recursive function, so to put it simply, I have an object:

```
var tts = require('./tts')
```

This object uses the Web API's Speech Synthesis functionality to turn the text that was passed in into speech.

So, I have a recursive function, say something, that should say the next thing, after the first one is done.

```
function saySomething(idx) {
    tts('first thing',saysomething.bind(this,'next thing'))
}
```

Unfortunately, however, this does not work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

[tts code](https://github.com/zwhitchcox/humor-me/blob/master/tts.js)

[recursive function code](https://github.com/zwhitchcox/humor-me/blob/master/index.js#L20)

P.S. I'm using browserify to compile the node-style code into browser-friendly code

Comment: Can you come up with a simple example? Your actual code is too complicated to make any sense :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tts()` is an asynchronous function that calls its callback when it's done, you can call the next thing when that is done like this:

```
function saySomething(idx) {
    tts('first thing', function() {
        tts('next thing');
    })
}
```

This would say `first thing` and then say `next thing` and then be done.  While, at first glance, this appears to be recursive, it does not accumulate a stack frame with each call like a regular recursive call would because of the asynchronous nature of the callback.  The first call to `tts()` has actually returned before the second one is called.

If what you really want to do is to iterate through an array of things to say, you can do that like this:

```
var phrases = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

function sayPhrases(items) {
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < items.length) {
            tts(items[index++], next);
        }
    }
    next();
}

sayPhrases(phrases);
```

Comment: AhhhhhhHow did I not see that?? I could have sworn I tried that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ZaneHitchcox - I added an example if you want to iterate through an array of things to say.